Не работает змейка
Взял змейку с гитхаба, переписал и почему-то она не работает, ничего не отображается.


// В этом файле функции, которые использует программа

/*
    Функция отрисовывает прямоугольник.
    Принимает объект с параметрами для отрисовки
    (Коордитнаты левого верхнего угла,
    ширина и высота прямоугольника, цвет заливки)
*/
function drawRect (param) {
    // Новая геометрическая фигура
    context.beginPath();
    // Обозначить прямоугольник
    context.rect(param.x, param.y, param.width, param.height);
    context.fillStyle = param.fillColor;
    context.fill();
}

// Функция очищает канвас
function clearCanvas() {
    // Очистить канвас - короткая запись
    // canvas.width = canvas.width;

    // Очистить канвас по канону, как предусмртрено в JS
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Функция создает игровое поле. Принимает кол-во колонок и строк
function createGameMap(columns, rows) {
    // Карта игрового поля.
    const map = [];
    
    // Заполнить карту игрового поля
    for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
        const row = [];

        for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            row.push({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                // Есть ли змейка?
                snake: false,
                // Есть ли еда?
                food: false,
                // Есть ли плохая еда?
                badFood: false
            })
        }

        map.push(row);
    }

    return map;
}

// Функция возвращает случайную свободную от змейки и еды ячейку
function getRandomFreeCell(map) {
    // Все свободные ячейки
    const freeCells = [];

    /*
        map.flat() делает массив плоским (убирает 1 уровень вложенности).
        [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].flat() -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        Если передать параметр Infinity (уберет все уровни вложенности):
        [[['a', 'b', 'c'], 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].flat(Infinity) -> ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    */
   // Пройти по всем ячейкам на карте
   for (const cell of map.flat()) {
    // Если ячейка не пустая:
    if (cell.snake || cell.food) {
        // Такая ячейка НЕ подходит,перейти к следующей
        continue;
    }

    // Пустую ячейку положить в массив свободных ячеек
    freeCells.push(cell);
   }

   // Случайный индекс среди всех индексов массива свободных ячеек
   const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * freeCells.length)
   // Вернуть случайную свободную ячейку
   return freeCells[index];
}

// Функция отрисовывает карту.
function drawGameMap(map) {
    // Пройти по всем ячейкам
    for (const cell of map.flat()) {
        const param = {
            // Координаты левого верхнего угла
            x: GAME_PADDING + cell.x * (CELL_MARGIN + CELL_MARGIN),
            y: GAME_PADDING + cell.y * (CELL_SIZE + CELL_MARGIN),
            // Ширина и высота прямоугольника
            width: CELL_SIZE,
            height: CELL_SIZE,
            // Цвет заливки
            fillColor: FREE_COLOR
        }

        // Если ячейка с едой:
        if (cell.food) {
            param.fillColor = FOOD_COLOR;
        }

        // Если ячейка с плохой едой:
        if (cell.badFood) {
            param.fillColor = BAD_FOOD_COLOR;
        }

        // Если в ячейке змейка:
        if (cell.snake) {
            param.fillColor = SNAKE_COLOR;
        }

        // Отрисовтаь выбранную ячейку
        drawRect(param);
    }
}

// Функция возвращает ячейку карты по координатам x, y
function getCell(x, y) {
    // Если вышла за левую границу поля:
    if (x < 0) {
        // Вернуться с правой стороны поля
        x += COLUMNS;
    }

    // Если вышла за правую страницу поля:
    if (x >= COLUMNS) {
        // Вернуться с левой стороны поля
        x -= COLUMNS;
    }

    // Если вышли за верхнюю границу поля:
    if (y < 0) {
        // Вернуться с нижней стороны поля
        y += ROWS;
    }

    // Если вышли за нижнюю границу поля:
    if (y >= ROWS) {
        // Вернуться с верхней стороны поля
        y -= ROWS;
    }

    // Пройти по всем ячейкам карты map
    for (const cell of map.flat()) {
        // Если ячейка совпадает с искомой
        if (cell.x === x && cell.y === y) {
            // Вернуть ячейку
            return cell;
        }
    }
}


// Функция передвигает змейку
function moveSnake() {
    // Пройти по всем ячейкам змейки кроме головы
    for (let i = snake.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        /*
            Заменим предыдущую ячейку на следующую по движению змейки
            (следующая станет там, где раньше была предыдущая)
        */
       snake[i] = snake[i - 1];
    }

    // Если змейка двигается влево:
    if (snakeDirect === 'left') {
        // Взять левую ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x - 1, snake[0].y);
    }

    // Если змейка двигается врпаво:
    else if (snakeDirect === "rigth") {
        // Взять правую ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x + 1, snake[0].y);
    }

    // Если змейка двигается вверх:
    else if (snakeDirect === 'up') {
        // Взять верхнюю ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x, snake[0].y - 1);
    }

    // Если змейка двигается вниз:
    else if (snakeDirect === "down") {
        // Взять нижнюю ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x, snake[0].y + 1);
    }

    // Пройти по всем ячейкам змейки
    for (const cell of snake) {
        // Отметить эти ячейки как ячейки со змейкой
        cell.snake = true;
    }
}

// Функция выводит информацию о состоянии игры
function showState() {
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.font = '20px sans-serif';
    context.textAlign = 'left';
    context.fillText(`Cooldown: ${cooldown}`, 10, 30);
    context.fillText(`Очки: ${snake.length * 5}`, 10, 50);
}

// Функция показывает сообщение в канвасе во время игровой паузы
function drawPaused() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
    context.fill();

    context.font = "50px sans-serif";
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillText(`Ваш счёт: ${snake.length * 5}`, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

    context.font = "30px sans-serif";
    context.fillText("Нажмите Enter чтобы продолжить", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 + 50);

}

// Функция инициализирует игру
function init() {
    map = createGameMap(COLUMNS, ROWS);

    const cell = getRandomFreeCell(map);

    snake = [cell];

    cell.snake = true;

    snakeDirect = 'up';
    nextSnakeDirect = 'up';
    play = true;
    cooldown = START_COOLDOWN;

    // Положить еду в случайную свободную ячейку
    getRandomFreeCell(map).food = true;
    // Положить плохую едум в случайную свободную ячейку
    getRandomFreeCell(map).badFood = true;
}

// snake.js

// В этом файле функции, которые использует программа.

/*
    Функция отрисовывает прямоугольник.
    Принимает объект с параметрами для отрисовки
    (Координаты левого верхнего угла,
    ширина и высота прямоугольника, цвет заливки).
*/
function drawRect (param) {
    // Новая геометрическая фигура.
    context.beginPath()
    // Обозначить прямоугольник.
    context.rect(param.x, param.y, param.width, param.height)
    context.fillStyle = param.fillColor
    context.fill()
}

// Функция очищает канвас.
function clearCanvas () {
    // Очистить канвас - короткая запись.
    // canvas.width = canvas.width

    // Очистить канвас по канону, как предусмотрено в JS.
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}

// Функция создаёт игровое поле. Принимает количество колонок и строк.
function createGameMap (columns, rows) {
    // Карта игрового поля.
    const map = []

    // Заполнить карту игрового поля.
    for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
        const row = []

        for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            row.push({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                // Есть ли змейка?
                snake: false,
                // Есть ли еда?
                food: false,
                // Есть ли плохая еда?
                badFood: false
            })
        }

        map.push(row)
    }

    return map
}

// Функция возвращает случайную свободную от змейки и еды ячейку.
function getRandomFreeCell (map) {
    // Все свободные ячейки.
    const freeCells = []

    /*
        map.flat() делает массив плоским (убирает 1 уровень вложенности).
        [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].flat() -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        Если передать параметр Infinity (уберет все уровни вложенности):
        [[['a', 'b', 'c'], 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].flat(Infinity) -> ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    */
    // Пройти по всем ячейкам на карте.
    for (const cell of map.flat()) {
        // Если ячейка НЕ пустая:
        if (cell.snake || cell.food) {
            // Такая ячейка НЕ подходит, перейти к следующей.
            continue
        }

        // Пустую ячейку положить в массив свободных ячеек.
        freeCells.push(cell)
    }

    // Случайный индекс среди всех индексов массива свободных ячеек.
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * freeCells.length)
    // Вернуть случайную свободную ячейку.
    return freeCells[index]
}

// Функция отрисовывает карту.
function drawGameMap (map) {
    // Пройти по всем ячейкам.
    for (const cell of map.flat()) {
        const param = {
            // Координаты левого верхнего угла.
            x: GAME_PADDING + cell.x * (CELL_SIZE + CELL_MARGIN),
            y: GAME_PADDING + cell.y * (CELL_SIZE + CELL_MARGIN),
            // Ширина и высота прямоугольника.
            width: CELL_SIZE,
            height: CELL_SIZE,
            // Цвет заливки.
            fillColor: FREE_COLOR
        }

        // Если ячейка с едой:
        if (cell.food) {
            param.fillColor = FOOD_COLOR
        }

        // Если ячейка с плохой едой:
        if (cell.badFood) {
            param.fillColor = BAD_FOOD_COLOR
        }

        // Если в ячейке змейка:
        if (cell.snake) {
            param.fillColor = SNAKE_COLOR
        }

        // Отрисовать выбранную ячейку.
        drawRect(param)
    }
}

// Функция возвращает ячейку карты по координатам x, y.
function getCell (x, y) {
    // Если вышли за левую границу поля:
    if (x < 0) {
        // Вернуться с правой стороны поля.
        x += COLUMNS
    }

    // Если вышли за правую границу поля:
    if (x >= COLUMNS) {
        // Вернуться с левой стороны поля.
        x -= COLUMNS
    }

    // Если вышли за верхнюю границу поля:
    if (y < 0) {
        // Вернуться с нижней стороны поля.
        y += ROWS
    }

    // Если вышли за нижнюю границу поля:
    if (y >= ROWS) {
        // Вернуться с верхней стороны поля.
        y -= ROWS
    }

    // Пройти по всем ячейкам карты map.
    for (const cell of map.flat()) {
        // Если ячейка совпадает с искомой.
        if (cell.x === x && cell.y === y) {
            // Вернуть ячейку.
            return cell
        }
    }
}

// Функция передвигает змейку.
function moveSnake () {
    // Пройти по всем ячейкам змейки кроме головы.
    for (let i = snake.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        /*
            Заменим предыдущую ячейку на следующую по движению змейки 
            (следующая станет там, где раньше была предыдущая).
        */
        snake[i] = snake[i - 1]
    }

    // Если змейка двигается влево:
    if (snakeDirect === 'left') {
        // Взять левую ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки.
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x - 1, snake[0].y)
    }

    // Если змейка двигается вправо:
    else if (snakeDirect === 'right') {
        // Взять правую ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки.
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x + 1, snake[0].y)
    }

    // Если змейка двигается вверх:
    else if (snakeDirect === 'up') {
        // Взять верхнюю ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки.
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x, snake[0].y - 1)
    }

    // Если змейка двигается вниз:
    else if (snakeDirect === 'down') {
        // Взять нижнюю ячейку от головы змейки и установить новую голову змейки.
        snake[0] = getCell(snake[0].x, snake[0].y + 1)
    }

    // Пройти по всем ячейкам на карте.
    for (const cell of map.flat()) {
        // Отметить все ячейки как ячейки без змейки.
        cell.snake = false
    }

    // Пройти по всем ячейкам змейки.
    for (const cell of snake) {
        // Отметить эти ячейки как ячейки со змейкой.
        cell.snake = true
    }
}

// Функция выводит информацию о состоянии игры.
function showState () {
    context.fillStyle = 'black'
    context.font = "20px sans-serif"
    context.textAlign = "left"
    context.fillText(`Cooldown: ${cooldown}`, 10, 30)
    context.fillText(`Очки: ${snake.length * 5}`, 10, 50)
}

// Функция показывает сообщение на канвасе во время игровой паузы.
function drawPaused () {
    context.beginPath()
    context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'
    context.fill()

    context.font = "50px sans-serif"
    context.fillStyle = 'black'
    context.textAlign = "center"
    context.fillText(`Ваш счет: ${snake.length * 5}`, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)

    context.font = "30px sans-serif"
    context.fillText("Нажмите Enter чтобы продолжить", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 + 50)
}

// Функция инициализирует игру.
function init () {
    map = createGameMap(COLUMNS, ROWS)

    const cell = getRandomFreeCell(map)

    snake = [cell]

    cell.snake = true

    snakeDirect = 'up'
    nextSnakeDirect = 'up'
    play = true
    cooldown = START_COOLDOWN

    // Положить еду в случайную свободную ячейку.
    getRandomFreeCell(map).food = true
    // Положить плохую еду в случайную свободную ячейку.
    getRandomFreeCell(map).badFood = true
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SnakeGame</title>

    <style>
        
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script src="snake.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Ну так бери и дебажь...


так 2 скрипта или 1? 2) функция init 2 раза объявлена? а где она вызывается?

